# How to rewrite /archive/* to /post/* in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, blogengine.net

I'm trying to migrate from SubText to BlogEngine.NET and I want to keep the links to the old posts working.
The URLs are very similar, previously they were:

```
http://server/archive/year/month/day/name-of-the-post.aspx
```

and now they are

```
http://server/post/year/month/day/name-of-the-post.aspx
```

I'm using IIS 7.5 with ASP.NET 4.0 in Integrated Mode. What's the best way to rewrite the "/archive/" to "/post/", knowing that I now also have a http://server/archive.aspx that has to keep working?

Best Regards,
Gustavo Guerra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing to do is use the extension:

**SEO Redirection**

http://www.blogenginewall.com/post/2011/04/01/BlogEngine-SEO-Permanent-Redirection-From-Old-URL-To-New-URL.aspx

Real easy to use and this is what I use.

All you do is put:

Old URl: http://server/archive/year/month/day/name-of-the-post.aspx

New URL: http://server/post/year/month/day/name-of-the-post.aspx

Thats it!

Not only does it redirect but will also return a 301 Status to the search engines telling them that the old URL is no longer being used and to use the new instead url.

This way it also updates the search engines.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't found that extension. With a little tweaking to use StartsWith instead of Equals it will do just what I want